# How to convert CSV to a nested JSON array using Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, csv, azure-data-factory, etl

I'm facing a pretty interesting task to convert an arbitrary CSV file to a JSON structure following this schema:

```
{
    "Data": [
        ["value_1", "value_2"],
        ["value_3", "value_4"]
    ]
}
```

In this case, the input file will look like this:

```
value_1,value_2
value_3,value_4
```

The requirement is to use Azure Data Factory and I won't be able to delegate this task to Azure Functions or other services.
I'm thinking about using 'Copy data' activity but can't get my mind around the configuration. `TabularTranslator` seems to only work with a definite number of columns but the CSV that I can receive can contain any number of columns.
Maybe DataFlows can help me but their setup doesn't look to be an easy one either. Plus, if I get it correctly, DataFlows take more time to start up.

So, basically, I just need to take the CSV content and put it into "Data" 2d array.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Where is your CSV file present?

Comment: @SaideepArikontham It's on Blob Storage. I read it using a DataSet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve this requirement, using `Copy data` or `TabularTranslator` is complicated. This can be achieved using dataflows in the following way.

- First create a source dataset using the following configurations. This allows us to read entire row as a single column value (string):

[image]

- Import the projection and name the column as `data`. The following is how the data preview looks like:

[image]

- Now, first split these column values using `split` function in `derived column` transformations. I am replacing the same column using `split(data,',')`.

[image]

- Then, I have added a `key` column with a constant value 'x' so that I can group all rows and covert the grouped data into array of arrays.

[image]

- The data would look like this after the above step:

[image]

- Use `aggregate` transformation to group by the above created column and use `collect` aggregate function to create array of arrays (`collect(data)`).

[image]

- Use `select` transformation to select only the above created column `Data`.

[image]

- Finally, in the sink, select your destination and create a sink JSON dataset. Choose `output to single file` in settings and give a file name.

[image]

- Create dataflow pipeline activity and run the above dataflow. The file will be created, and it looks like the following:

[image]